# finding even numbers in the array issue (C++)

Tags: c++

My code is to extract odd number and even number in an 1D array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a[6] = {1,6,3,8,5,10};
    int odd[]={};
    int even[]={};

    for (int i=0; i < 6; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }

    for (int i=0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (a[i] % 2 == 1) {
            odd[i] = a[i];
            cout << odd[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << " " << endl;

    for (int i=0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (a[i] % 2 == 0) {
            even[i] = a[i];
            cout << even[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the output is:

```
1
3
5

2
1
6
```

It shows that it successfully extract odd numbers but the same method applied to the even number. It comes with an issue while the even number is 4.

Could anyone help me find the cause here? Thanks.

Comment: You need to declare the size of `odd` and `even`. They're defaulting to 0 elements, so you're assigning outside the bounds.

Comment: This `int odd[]={};` isn't valid C++. Arrays must have non-zero sizes, determined from compile-time constants.

Comment: You can use a `std::vector<int>`, and then you can add numbers to this dynamically with `.push_back()`.

Comment: another option is to change `odd[]` to `odd[6]`

Comment: btw, consider using `sizeof(array)` or even `countof(array)`, `_countof` or similar in for loop expressions. When you manually specify same size of array in four different places, you'll probably got some problems when modifying this code later.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an Undefined Behavior, so result may be any, even random, even formatted hard drive.

`int odd[] = {}` is the same as `int odd[/*count  of elements inside {}*/] = {/*nothing*/}`, so it's `int odd[0];`

Result is not defined when you're accessing elements besides the end of array.
You probably have to think about correct odd/even arrays size, or use another auto-sizeable data structure.

Answer (score 1):

First, although not causing a problem, you initialize an array with data and then overwrite it.  The code

```cpp
int a[6] = {1,6,3,8,5,10};
```

can be replaced with

```cpp
int a[6];
```

Also, as stated in the comments,

```cpp
int odd[]={};
```

isn't valid.  You should either allocate a buffer as big as the main buffer (6 ints) or use a vector (although I personally prefer c-style arrays for small sizes, because they avoid heap allocations and extra complexity).  With the full-size buffer technique, you need a value like `-1` (assuming you intend to only input positive numbers) to store after the list of values in the arrays to tell your output code to stop reading, or store the sizes somewhere.  This is to prevent reading values that haven't been set.

I don't understand your problem when 4 is in the input.  Your code looks fine except for your arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::vector< int > odd;` and then call only `odd.push_back(elem)` whem `elem` is odd.